# Flutter: Image going out of alignment

Tags: flutter, dart

Here I am trying to put an image on a specific part of the screen as seen in the beginning of the video below. At any set height, the screen sort of zooms in or enlarges a bit. Especially the image, it enlarges and center aligns itself when I try to bring down the notification bar of my phone. I have attached the codes below.

[The video of the issue I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJdQu.jpg)

```
// onboarding_screen_1.dart

class OnboardingScreen1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const OnboardingScreen1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: colorPrimary,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.15,
          ),
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
            alignment: Alignment(-22, 0),
            child: Image(
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/onboarding-1.png'),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.05,
          ),
          const Text(
            'Carpool with neighbours',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.025,
          ),
          const Text(
            'Find neighbours from your area\nand carpool with them',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `Alignment(-22, 0)` really?

Comment: @Nagual I know right? Beats me! When I make the beight `height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3` i put the alignment to something like `(-3.5, 0)`, I can't remember exactly what I put.

Comment: Provide `Alignment(x, y)` x y value -1 to 1 and it would be better if you could attach an image of your desire output

Comment: @YeasinSheikh The video I attached is the desired output. The issue I am facing, as in the video, the image goes out of the alignment. And with the alignment values -1 to 1, the image does not seem to move about much.